# Remap netrw keys

Tags: key-bindings, netrw

I have a problem since the last Vim update that is driving me crazy. I don't know if it's actually related to the update, but since I didn't change anything in my config that's my best guess.

I've mapped `leader` to `-` and `:q` to `<leader>q`. It always worked without any problem and it's one of those combinations that I perform without thinking.

The problem is, I've found out today, that `-` is mapped in `netrw` to go up one level in the directory tree. Since a couple of days, when I load `netrw`, Vim started to perform the default action instead of considering `-` as my leader, so every time I try to close a window with `netrw` in it, Vim goes up one level and starts recording a macro instead of doing `:q`.

My question is this: how can I unmap the default `-` behavior in `netrw` and restore my `leader` mapping?

And if anyone happens to know why this started happening in the last couple of days, I'd be very happy to know.

Comment: What is the exact command you use?

Comment: I have `nnoremap <Leader>q :q<CR>` in my vimrc, and I usually typed `-q` to close the window. It still works when netrw is not loaded.

Comment: With the cursor in a netrw window, do `:verbose map -`.

Comment: It gets set by netrw: `@:call <SNR>66_NetrwBrowseUpDir(1)<CR> Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.903/share/vim/vim74/autoload/netrw.vim`

Comment: The issue disappeared yesterday, again without changing anything in the configuration or plugin. A hell of a mistery.